# how to scroll a div element when scrolling to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone help me how the div has to display when i click on a link at the bottom of the page?

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there are links bottom of the page. Though when i click on the links at the bottom, the div(the video div) is displayed at the top of the page. But i want the div should be displayed where i click on the div.

Following is portion my html:

```
<body>
<div id="ActualContentBox">
        <h2 align="center"> Selenium WebDriver Videos</h2>
        <h4 align="center"><i>Click on any link below to watch the Video</i></h4><br/>
        <ul>
            <h3>
                <li>How to Install Eclipse and configure Selenium WebDriver</li>
            </h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="playvideo" onclick="playMe('G2KlPOYu6U8')">How to Install Eclipse and configure Selenium WebDriver</a></li>
            </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="videoDiv" style="display:none;">
            <div id="titleHeaderDiv">
                <a href="#" ><img id="closeDiv" src="images/close-1.png" alt="Click to close" onclick="closeDivFunc()"></a>
            </div>
            <iframe id="video1" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
</body>
```

Following is my css:

```
div#ActualContentBox
{
    border: 5px groove #BEB5B2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}

div#overlayDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    background:red;
    background-image: url("../images/transparent.jpg");
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    left: 135px;
    top: 175px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

div#videoDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 300px;
    border: 5px groove #BEB5B2;
    height:360px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#titleHeaderDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    background-color:#F1F1F1;
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
}

img#closeDiv
{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

iframe#video1
{
    position: relative;
    /*bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;*/

    top:50px;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the position of `#videoDiv` to `position:fixed;`?

Comment: As i said, in below comment, when i set to fixed, though the div displayed at fixed location, the page is scrolling to the top of the page.

Comment: well you can get rid of the `#` in the href and just set that blank so it won't scroll up.

Comment: well, tried that. The moment i click on a link the video div is displayed and suddenly closes and the cursor pointing to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a video div inside each list item and have it hidden by default. When you click the link, then show the video.

If you only want one instance of the video, then you can get the pageX and pageY of the cursor and display the video at that location.

**HTML**

```
<li class="video-container">
    <a href=""></a>
    <div class="video"></div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    display: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.video-container > a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
});
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Ok, though the div is fixed, the cursor is scrolling to the top of the page, so basically it is showing the first page screen. doest it happening because of the code which exists before by body: <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".scroll").click(function(event){  
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
      });
     });
    </script>